.cpanel.yml for WordPress deployment
I’m trying to setup cPanel Git Version Control to deploy a WordPress site from BitBucket.  The.cpanel.yml file I envisioned is

---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/mysite/public_html/
    - /bin/rm -rf /home/mysite/public_html/wp-admin
    - /bin/cp -R wp-admin $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/rm -rf /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content
    - /bin/rm -rf /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes
    - /bin/cp -R wp-content $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp -R wp-includes $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/rm -rf /home/mysite/public_html/.htaccess
    - /bin/cp -R .htaccess $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/rm /home/mysite/public_html/*.php
    - /bin/cp -f *.php $DEPLOYPATH

which works fine, except the .php files (index.php, wp-activate.php, etc.) are not getting deployed, so there’s something wrong with the last line.  Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong there?
I also tried listing each .php file individually, such as
- /bin/cp wp-config.php $DEPLOYPATH

but that didn’t work either.

This does not answer your question, but I would highly recommend not keeping any core files or wp-config in BitBucket. Your deploy should really only include what's in the wp-content directory, since those are the only files that should be getting modifications by you.

I can understand not keeping wp-config.php on BB, but my goal is to update WP on my local machine and push the changes to at first BB, then the site.  Seems like a normal workflow to me, I just can’t figure out how to have .cpanel.yml copy the individual files as well.
